# Reinstalling Windows on Ubuntu machine, no Windows OS is installed at the moment

Tags: boot, usb, windows, system

Have a laptop from 2012, which was installed Windows 7 in it first. Then upgraded to Windows 10. Suddenly, I was forced to switch to Ubuntu like 2 weeks ago, so I switched to it. And the problem starts since the beginning. Tried installing as dual boot, but didn't work my way, so I backed up my files, then performed a clean installation of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS*(Formatted my hdd entirely)*. My laptop does have CD/DVD rom, but I don't have Windows Installation CD/DVD. It is urgent so I can't ask for someone to lend me one.

Linux OSes doesn't support my printer, so I need to switch back. But I can't do it now. The problem is that I am trying for like 5 hours.

[Reference1](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/make-bootable-windows-10-usb-install.html). Followed this lead to no success.

Also tried this method which is [UNetBootin](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/using-unetbootin-to-create-a-linux-usb-from-linux/) method. Didn't work again. Gave me only "Default" option in the boot state. There are 2 solutions for my [error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493440/unetbootin-is-stuck-in-an-automatic-boot-in-10-seconds-countdown-loop) here. 1st one says that try WoeUSB *formerly WinUSB*. 2nd one says me to reinstall UNetBootin. Tried reinstalling UNetBootin, then using it gave me the same error.

Error message is as follows: [image]

PS. Googled UNetBootin error image then screenshot it.

Comment: Download Windows 10 ISO image from Microsoft website. Burn into DVD. Install. Ask Windows for details.

Comment: It's 3 AM in here. I can't find open shop which could sell me DVD. And it's so urgent that I need my printer get worked at 7 AM.

Comment: what printer do you have?

Comment: Canon LBP1120. There are tutorials out there and doesn't work for me. So I thought it's not supported. Tried CUPS method to try to install.

Comment: You have a USB drive inserted in your computer. Can you not burn Windows onto that using startup disk creator and the windows iso? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO

Also, what printer do you have? Maybe someone here can troubleshoot that so you don't have to switch right now.