# Windows USB drive from ubuntu failing repeteadly

Tags: live-usb, windows-10, woeusb

I'm trying to boot a USB with Windows-10 and making it bootable from Linux (Ubuntu).

For this purpose, I installed Woe-USB as a snap package. The USB drive is formatted to `exfat`.

I get this weird error:

```
sudo woe-usb.woeusb --device ~/Desktop/Win10_2004_EnglishInternational_x64.iso /dev/sdb
WoeUSB v@@WOEUSB_VERSION@@
==============================
/snap/woe-usb/21/bin/woeusb: line 918: /bin/mount: Permission denied
/snap/woe-usb/21/bin/woeusb: line 899: /bin/mount: Permission denied
Mounting source filesystem...
mkdir: cannot create directory '/media/woeusb_source_1590608570_38263': Permission denied                                             
mount_source_filesystem: Error: Unable to create "/media/woeusb_source_1590608570_38263" mountpoint directory
/snap/woe-usb/21/bin/woeusb: line 1302: /bin/mount: Permission denied                                                                 
mount_source_filesystem: Error: Unable to mount source media
Error: Unable to mount source filesystem                                                                                              
/snap/woe-usb/21/bin/woeusb: line 899: /bin/mount: Permission denied                                                                  
You may now safely detach the target device
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a `/bin/mount: Permission denied mount_source_filesystem: Error: Unable to mount source media Error: Unable to mount source filesystem` error. Connect the woe-usb:removable-media plug to the woe-usb:removable-media slot in order to enable USB devices to be mounted automatically by WoeUSB.

1. Search for woeusb in Ubuntu Software and click it to go to the woe-usb screen.
2. Click the Permissions button.
3. Toggle the *Read/Write files on removeable storage devices* slider from OFF to ON as shown in the below screenshot.
4. Authenticate with your user password when the *Authentication Required* window pops up.

[image: woe-usb Permissions]

Answer (score 1):

### Install

- [Enable snaps on Ubuntu and install woe-usb](https://snapcraft.io/install/woe-usb/ubuntu)

### Fix Permissions

It is happening because [WoeUSB](https://github.com/WoeUSB/WoeUSB) running under `/snap` "partition", to fix this, just copy it to a different location, for example:

```
sudo cp -v /snap/woe-usb/21/bin/woeusb /usr/bin/
```

### Usage

```
sudo /usr/bin/woeusb --device PATHTO.iso /dev/sdb --target-filesystem NTFS
```

***Note**: Make sure to change `PATHTO.iso` to the desired image, and `/dev/sdb` to the correct USB device (you can use `sudo blkid` to see your devices), and NTFS, otherwise, see the supported list.*