# not able to write linux iso to a usb drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, usb

I have a 4GB HP flash drive with FAT32 file system. I'm trying to create a bootable usb drive with an iso file: `slitaz-rolling.iso` [ SliTaz is a lighweight linux distro ].

I tried `uNetBootin` but got into this issue: [UNetbootin is stuck in an “Automatic boot in 10 seconds” countdown loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493440/unetbootin-is-stuck-in-an-automatic-boot-in-10-seconds-countdown-loop). Using this tool, I'm able to write large iso files like ubuntu, lubuntu, centos, etc. but not the smaller ones like the one above.

Then I tried `Startup Disk Creator` which wouldn't even recognize the iso file (again, unless it's ubuntu, lubuntu, centos, or some other large distro, SDC wouldn't recognize the iso). Then I read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396177/startup-disk-creator-not-recognizing-selected-iso-in-13-10) that changing the file extension from `iso` to `img` might work,  which actually did work but after completion nothing got written to the usb drive, it was still empty. I tried a couple times but to no avail.

Then I tried the `dd` command, like this:

```
 sudo dd bs=4M if=slitaz-rolling.iso of=/dev/sdb conv=fdatasync status=progress
```

It runs till completion and I got this:

```
147046400 bytes (147 MB, 140 MiB) copied, 120.971 s, 1.2 MB/s
```

But when I check the flash drive, I got nothing. It's empty.

So, what should I do now? or am I missing something? please let me know. thanks.

Comment: You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035), and if you are lucky, solve it.

Comment: try using Rufus to make the bootable usb drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mkusb` tool worked for me. this is how I installed it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution

Comment: @sudodus thanks to you for commenting this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you may have not written the complete ISO on your USB stick. The following commandline worked for me many times before:

**Be sure to have the drive unmounted!**

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=Your/path/to.iso of=/dev/sdX status=progress oflag=sync
```

where sdX must be substituted. Note that `oflag=sync` ensures that dd returns AFTER all the data has been written on /dev/sdX...